# How to place the cursor at the end of a line in edittext

Tags: android-edittext

In the case of forced newline, the cursor can be positioned at the end of the line.
However, in the case of automatic new line, the cursor cannot be positioned at the end.

Is there any way to make it look like the expected situation below?

[image: My Current Situation]

[image: Expecting Situation]